# Arranging tennis matches so that all players play at least once.

Tags: combinatorics

Eight tennis players wish to play three doubles matches. Players must have different partners for each match and at the end of the three matches each player must have played in a match involving each of the other seven players at least once. Can this be arranged?

Comment: Three doubles matches involve 12 player-matches, so some of the 8 players will play in one or fewer matches, so some of the 8 players will play with only 3 or fewer of the other seven players, so a contradiction.

Comment: @peterwhy There are eight players. Each player wishes to play three doubles matches. This is unlike how you read it, where there are three matches total.

Answer (score 1):

Match one:

- $P_1P_2$ against $P_3P_4$
- $P_5P_6$ against $P_7P_8$

Match two:

- $P_1P_5$ against $P_2P_6$
- $P_3P_7$ against $P_4P_8$

Match three:

- $P_1P_8$ against $P_2P_7$
- $P_3P_6$ against $P_4P_5$